# background-image gradient change in js not working

Tags: javascript, css, background

i have problem with this js code. Console log and conditions works properly, but the background is not changed.(changing background depend on time).

JS code here:

```
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours()



$(document).ready(function(){

if(time <6 || time > 21)
{   
 $('.tester').css({ 
  'background-image' : ' linear-gradient(#483475,#141852, #070B34,#000)',
  })
  console.log(1);
}

if(time >= 6 && time < 9)
{   
 $('.tester').css({ 
  'background-image' : ' linear-gradient(#c6c6dc,#a8b4d6, #fabf67,#f9a05a)',
  })
  console.log(2);
}

if(time >= 9 && time < 19)
{   
 $('.tester').css({ 
  'background-image' : ' linear-gradient(#2fcbff,#2f63ff, #fabf67,00b253)',
  })
  console.log(3);
}

if(time >= 19 && time < 21)
{   
 $('.tester').css({ 
  'background-image' : ' linear-gradient(#c6c6dc,#a8b4d6, #fabf67,#f9a05a)',
  })
 console.log(4); 

}






});
```

Here is the div inside html:

```
<div class='tester'> TEST </div>
```

and the style

```
.tester
{
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
color: white;
}
```

When i put it in something like that, it works properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


     $('.tester').css({ 
      'background-image' : ' linear-gradient(#483475,#141852, #070B34,#000)',
      })
      console.log(1);
    }
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code. The third `if` block is missing a `#` in the last colour

Comment: All these gradients appear to be static, it is not like you are calculating any values dynamically - so you should rather not be setting styles directly via JavaScript here, but keep this in your stylesheet. Have your JS code add an additional class to the `.tester` element based on what hour of the day it is, and then write rules in your stylesheet to apply the corresponding background gradient. `.tester.morning { … } .tester.midday { … } …`

Comment: But... why The log prompt in console Works properly? If I add breakpoints and debug it, These lines are not skipped - but nothing happens. Hovewer adding additional classes can be Better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the time passed every second to decide which background needs to be shown.

```js
const start_seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

setInterval(function() {
  const new_seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  const time = new_seconds - start_seconds;

  if (time < 6 || time > 21) {
    $('.tester').css({
      'background-image': ' linear-gradient(#483475,#141852, #070B34,#000)',
    })
    console.log(1);
  }

  if (time >= 6 && time < 9) {
    $('.tester').css({
      'background-image': ' linear-gradient(#c6c6dc,#a8b4d6, #fabf67,#f9a05a)',
    })
    console.log(2);
  }

  if (time >= 9 && time < 19) {
    $('.tester').css({
      'background-image': ' linear-gradient(#2fcbff,#2f63ff, #fabf67,00b253)',
    })
    console.log(3);
  }

  if (time >= 19 && time < 21) {
    $('.tester').css({
      'background-image': ' linear-gradient(#c6c6dc,#a8b4d6, #fabf67,#f9a05a)',
    })
    console.log(4);

  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.tester {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tester'> TEST </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to see a non-jQuery example (for comparison sake):

```
let aryOfTesterClassElements = [... document.getElementsByClassName("tester")];
let firstTester = aryOfTesterClassElements[0];
firstTester.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(#2fcbff,#2f63ff, #fabf67,00b253)`;
```